cuda device class data modification fails for large number of threads
I instantiate device only classes with large data members. Subsequently, the data members are modified by all cuda threads via class pointers.
The program works for small number of threads (for example, 1872 blocks and 512 threads per block). But larger number of thread cases fail with GPUassert: an illegal memory access was encountered t13.cu 109. I also ran compute-sanitizer. It gives no error when the program passes, but, when failing, gives error messages
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= Invalid __global__ write of size 4 bytes
=========     at 0xe0 in runYourClass(YourClass *)
=========     by thread (352,0,0) in block (0,0,0)
=========     Address 0x580 is out of bounds
=========     and is 8,688,499,328 bytes before the nearest allocation at 0x205e00000 of size 8,388,864 bytes

The entire code is below:
#include <new>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <iostream>

#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

class MyClass{
public:
  __device__ MyClass(int ni) : n(ni) {
    X = new float[n];
  }
  __device__ void Fill() {
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    //printf("My id is %d and n is %d\n", idx, n);
    X[idx] = (float)idx+1.23;
    //printf("My id is %d and X is %.2f\n", idx, X[idx]);
  }
  __device__ ~MyClass() {
    delete[] X;
    X = nullptr;
  }
  int n;
  float *X;
};

class YourClass{
public:
  __device__ YourClass(MyClass* mci) : mc(mci) {
    m = mc->n;
    Y = new float[m];
  }
  __device__ void Modify() {
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    //printf("My id is %d and m is %d\n", idx, m);
    Y[idx] = (mc->X)[idx]+5.;
    //printf("My id is %d and Y is %.2f\n", idx, Y[idx]);
  }
  __device__ void Move(float *f) {
    int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    f[idx] = Y[idx];
  }
  __device__ ~YourClass() {
    delete[] Y;
    Y = nullptr;
  }
  MyClass* mc;
  int m;
  float *Y;
};

__global__ void initMyClass(MyClass *mcp, int n) {
  int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  if (idx==0) new(mcp) MyClass(n);
}

__global__ void initYourClass(YourClass *ycp, MyClass *mcp) {
  int idx = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
  if (idx==0) new(ycp) YourClass(mcp);
}

__global__ void runMyClass(MyClass *mcp) {
  mcp->Fill();
}

__global__ void runYourClass(YourClass *ycp) {
  ycp->Modify();
}

__global__ void moveYourClassData(YourClass *ycp, float *f) {
  ycp->Move(f);
}

__global__ void cleanUpDeviceClasses(MyClass *mcp, YourClass *ycp) {
  mcp->~MyClass();
  ycp->~YourClass();
}

int main() {
  //int nBLK=16384;
  //int nTPB=256;
  int nBLK=1872;
  int nTPB=512;
  int n=nBLK*nTPB;
  MyClass *mc;
  gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc(&mc, sizeof(MyClass)) );
  YourClass *yc;
  gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc(&yc, sizeof(YourClass)) );
  initMyClass<<<1,1>>>(mc, n);
  gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
  gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
  runMyClass<<<nBLK,nTPB>>>(mc);
  gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
  gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
  initYourClass<<<1,1>>>(yc, mc);
  gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
  gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
  runYourClass<<<nBLK,nTPB>>>(yc);
  gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
  gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );

  float *h_result = new float[n];
  float *d_result;
  gpuErrchk( cudaMalloc(&d_result, n*sizeof(float)) );
  moveYourClassData<<<nBLK,nTPB>>>(yc, d_result);
  gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
  gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
  gpuErrchk( cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_result, n*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) );
  for (int i=0;i<n;++i) {
    std::cout<<"i: "<<i<<", value: "<<h_result[i]<<'\n';
  }

  cleanUpDeviceClasses<<<1,1>>>(mc, yc);
  gpuErrchk( cudaPeekAtLastError() );
  gpuErrchk( cudaDeviceSynchronize() );
  cudaFree(mc);
  cudaFree(yc);
  cudaFree(d_result);
  delete[] h_result;
  return 0;
}


any time you use non-placement new in device code, you should be aware that you are allocating out of a limited size "device heap". The default maximum there is 8MB.  For small cases that pass, your allocations are successful.  For the large (commented-out) cases that don't work, your allocations are not successful.  You can increase the size of the device heap, and in any event you should test the returned pointer for NULL before assuming it is safe to use. When I add that kind of test to your code, I get an indication that the returned pointer for some of your new allocations is NULL

@RobertCrovella, The two classes in the code are in the (large) device global memory. Are the rest of the class (other than those members allocated with new) in the stack? (I am not familiar with the composition of the global memory) Is cudaDeviceSetLimit a reliable way for a production code? How else can I handle a large array of unknown size that is a member of a device class? Should I cudaMalloc from the host and connect that to the device object?; I would like to avoid this option. How can I take advantage of the fact that my classes are in the large device global memory?

no, cudaDeviceSetLimit() is not a reliable method for a large array of "unknown size" that is being allocated from device code.  Hopefully that should be self evident.  You won't on any current GPU be able to allocate an array of 300TB from device code.  So the first step if you want to use device allocation "reliably" is to either have a good handle on the upper bound for the array size, or provide a graceful recovery path if the allocation exceeds what you had previously set as the limit.  Otherwise use cudaMalloc.

I guess what I meant was if cudaDeviceSetLimit is a reliable way, provided it is based on a good estimate of the data size, which is smaller than the global memory size. Or is this something you would rather avoid for a production code due to whatever reason?

For a single allocation, I have no doubt that cudaDeviceSetLimit is a reliable way to provide for that allocation.  If you do many smaller allocations, as you have done here, then two factors that come into play are: 1. What is the allocation granularity.  2.  How much allocation can be outstanding per thread?   Just like any C++ code, its good practice to have a delete corresponding to each new (which you seem to have).  Then you should be able to calculate the max possible per thread, and then use occupancy to figure out what the max size needed is.  Then the limit should be reliable.
